# PHP - CodeIgniter - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to write a site with CodeIgniter but I've a problem with PHP. I'm sure that it's so simple and can't be wrong. But I don't know bugs from , just a newbie of CodeIgniter :)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">

        <div class="box">
              <div class="title">
                 <h4 class="clearfix">
                    <span class="left"><?php echo $title;?></span>
                </h4>
            </div>
          <div class="content">

            <form action="<?php echo current_url();?>" method="post">

              <div class="span2">  
                <select name="month">
                  <?php foreach($options['months'] as $montht){
                  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $montht['month'];?>"><?php echo turkcetarih('F','2013-'.$montht['month'].'-01');?></option> 
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>

                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="span2">
                <select name="year">
                  <?php foreach($options['years'] as $yeart){
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $yeart['year'];?>"><?php echo $yeart['year'];?></option>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?> 
                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="span3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Göster</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php if($charts):?>
        <div class="box">

            <div class="title">
                 <h4 class="clearfix">

                    <span class="left"><?php echo turkcetarih('F Y',$year.'-'.$month.'-01');?> Site Dökümü</span>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="content noPad">

                <table class="responsive table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Tarih</td>
                        <th>İzlenme</td>
                        <th>Yeni Üye</th>
                        <th>Eklenen İçerik</th>
                        <th>Yeni Yorum</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    for($i=0;$i<count($charts['day']);$i++)
                     {

                    ?>

                      <tr>
                            <td><?php echo turkcetarih('d F Y',$charts['year'][$i].'-'.$charts['month'][$i].'-'.$charts['day'][$i]);?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $charts['hit'][$i];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $charts['user'][$i];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $charts['video'][$i];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $charts['comment'][$i];?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php 
                      }
                      ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div><!-- End .box -->
        <?php else:?>
            <div class="well"> <p> <strong><?php echo turkcetarih('F Y',$year.'-'.$month.'-01');?></strong> için grafik dökümü bulunmamaktadır.</p></div>
        <?php endif;?>

    </div><!-- End .span12 -->
</div>
```

I've a bug from this file :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach() Filename: admin/dashboard_charts.php
>   Line Number: 28

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Hi, it looks like your `$options['months']` variable is not an array, try adding a `var_dump($options['months'])` just before the foreach to see what's inside that variable. If similar error, try `var_dump($options)`, if it fails be sure you are passing that variable from your controller - EDIT: actually, please tell us the line 28 of that file, it has to be a foreach statement, so `var_dump` the variable passed to the foreach in that line

Comment: Line 28 is : <?php foreach($options['years'] as $yeart){

Comment: Error Is self descriptive.

Comment: Did you [searched with your error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+PHP+Error+was+encountered+Severity%3A+Warning+Message%3A+Invalid+argument+supplied+for+foreach%28%29+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) before asking here?

Comment: Post your controller and model code as well

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you pass a non array type argument in `foreach` thus before `foreach` you check whether that argument is array type or not:

```
    if(is_array($options['months']))
     {
          foreach($options['months'] as $month)
        {
        // do something you want
        }
    else
    {
     // do something when get error 
    }
```

If the code goes into the `else` part then you first need to check your controller what you pass in view.

Answer (score 0):

When you return data from your model it come as **Object Array**. So  you have to pass your data to view as array.

We write this code **in Controller** to pass data.

Ex:

```
$data['options']=$this->Your_Model_Name->Function_Name_Which_Gives_data()
```

in **Model**

```
public Function_Name_Which_Gives_data()
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ....");//your argument 
 $result = $query->result_array();
return $result;//passing data as Objective Array
}
```

In **view**(For **Your answer**)

```
<?php foreach($options as $yeart){
    //echo your data
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $yeart['year'];?>"><?php echo $yeart['year'];?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
}
```